# Hyperplane arrangement : The Shi arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, combinations, finite-fields, algebraic-combinatorics

I have been lately reading Hyperplane arrangement lectures by Richard Stanley on [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/sp06stanley.pdf](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis610/sp06stanley.pdf) . In lecture 5, Theorem 5.16 we define the characteristic polynomial of the Shi arrangement by $$X_{S_n}(t)=t(t-n)^{n-1}$$
I am struggling to understand part of the proof of the theorem. More precisely, why did we partition [n] into p-n blocks ? How did we know that the maximum number of blocks that we can have is p-n ? I think the rest of the proof is clear. I am just trying to know why we thought of p-n. Any ideas ?